# CodeIgniter function not show?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

### helper.website.php

```
public function load_top_players() { 
    $this->load->lib(array('rank_db', 'db'), array(HOST, USER, PASS,CHARACTERS));
    $query = $this->rank_db->query('SELECT name, access FROM users ORDER BY access DESC LIMIT 5');
    while($row = $query->fetch()) {
        $this->rank[] = array(
            'name'  => htmlspecialchars($row['name']),
            'level' => (int)$row['access']
        );
    }
    return $this->rank;
}
```

### view.header.php

```
<?php
$rank = load::get('website');
$i = 1;
foreach ($rank as $pos => $player) {
    $first = (in_array($i, array(1))) ? '' : '';
    $second = (in_array($i, array(2))) ? '' : '';
    echo '<tr style="'.$first.' '.$second.' '.$third.'">
        <td  >'.$i.'</td>
        <td>'.$player['name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$player['access'].'</td>
    </tr>';
    $i++;
}
?>
```

It shows a blank page, no errors no nothing!

Comment: Use error reporting on.

Comment: is on but nothing happen !

Comment: Can you try pinting $rank and tell what is the result?

Comment: i know the problem is from view.header.php , because if im edit query with missing tables , nothing happen

Comment: For starters I do not see any relationship between what you have shown in helper.website.php and view.header.php. With $rank = load::get('website'); Where is load::get() defined?

Comment: Blank Pages are due to syntax errors... In helper.website.php IN the line $this->load->lib(array('rank_db', 'db'), array(HOST, USER, PASS,CHARACTERS)); - should ->lib be ->library?There is a bunch of funky things in your code...Have you performed any debug at all?

Comment: What you want to do is see the errors. In CI you can set the ENVIRONMENT to development... Look in your index.php and check that for the development selection, that the Error reporting is enabled and that the error display settings are turned on. These "should" work in of a local Development system. Are you familiar with enabling error reporting and what server and what version CI are you running ( which I should have asked in the first place!)

Comment: In your header part, you can set `$first = '';` instead of current code because it will give as same result as `$first = (in_array($i, array(1))) ? '' : '';`. Same with variable `$second`. [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: $top = load::get('website')->top_players(); is the fix !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's showing a blank page because you didn't pass any data to your view file. For getting data in your view file you must load a view from your controller with some data. Syntax is-

```
<?php

class Your_Controller_Class extends CI_Controller {

   function your_function()
   {
      $data['data'] = 'Your data'; //get it from your model or whatever
      $this->load->view('your_view_file', $data);
   }

}
?>
```

and then access it from your view file.

Comment: $top = load::get('website')->top_players(); is the fix !

Answer (score 1):

**helper.website.php**

```
public function getOnlineCount(){
        $this->load->lib(array('rank_db', 'db'), array(HOST, USER, PASS, CHARACTERS));  
        return $this->registry->rank_db->snumrows('SELECT count(name) as count from users where status <> -1 AND sub_status>= 1');
    }
```

and in  in **view.header.php** `<?php echo load::get('website')->getOnlineCount() ; ?>` works perfect ! how can i transform that to my query

Comment: is possible to change that function to what i have in first Question ?